# Unable to handle Too many SOQL queries Even after BULKIFY: 101

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, controller

I have requirement like to display related records related to leads with sic code starts with.So i filtered with using Like operator but i am getting exception 101 exception.But i am not able to bulkify below code.

how to handle in this case.

```
    public class LeadController 
    {
        public String CurrentId;
        public List<Opportunity> newopplist{get;set;}
        public List<Opportunity> listopp{get;set;}

        public LeadController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
         CurrentId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        }

        public void search()
        {
            set<String> cityset=new set<String>();
            Map<String,String> citymap=new Map<String,String>();
            Map<String,String> statemap=new Map<String,String>();
            Map<String,String> Siccodes=new Map<String,String>();
            List<Opportunity> newopplist=new List<Opportunity>();
            for(Lead ld:[Select Id,City,State,SIC_Code_1__c from Lead where Id=:CurrentId ])
            {
                // cityset.add(ld.City);
                if(ld.City <> null)
                {
                    citymap.put(ld.City,ld.City);
                }
                if(ld.state <> null)
                {
                    statemap.put(ld.State,ld.State);
                }
                if(ld.SIC_Code_1__c <> null)
                {
                Siccodes.put(ld.SIC_Code_1__c, ld.SIC_Code_1__c);
                }
            }
            newopplist=[Select Id,Name,Account.name,Number_of_Units__c,StageName,account.SIC_Code__c,Type,
                        Billing_City__c,Billing_State_Province__c,account.SIC_Industry_Name__c,
                        account.No_of_active_units__c from Opportunity where StageName='Closed Won' ];
            listopp=new List<Opportunity>();
            for(Opportunity opp: newopplist)
            {          
                if(!Siccodes.isEmpty())
                {
                    Set<String> codes = new Set<String>();
                    for(String code:Siccodes.keySet())
                    {
                        codes.add(code + '%');
                    }
                    listopp=[Select Id,Name,StageName,Account.name,Number_of_Units__c,account.SIC_Code__c,Type,
                             Billing_City__c,Billing_State_Province__c,account.SIC_Industry_Name__c,
                             account.No_of_active_units__c from Opportunity where account.SIC_Code__c 
                             LIKE :codes and StageName='Closed Won' ORDER BY account.No_of_active_units__c Desc Limit 10];                    

                }
       }
}
```

I am hitting limits because of this query as per debug logs.

> Select
>   Id,Name,StageName,Account.name,Number_of_Units__c,account.SIC_Code__c,Type,
>                                    Billing_City__c,Billing_State_Province__c,account.SIC_Industry_Name__c,
>                                    account.No_of_active_units__c from Opportunity where account.SIC_Code__c 
>                                    LIKE :codes and StageName='Closed Won' ORDER BY account.No_of_active_units__c Desc Limit 10

Comment: When you know the Id why for loop SOQL for Lead. you are querying Opportunity twice and one of them in loop and selecting all closed won you will hit 50000 limit error in production for that. Not sure what is your requirement.

Comment: Even i bulkified above query i dont have any other criteria to filter @battery.cord

Comment: Your code is not bulkified. It's clear you did not read the linked duplicate. I suggest taking a look at the later sections of the answer, which cover removing queries from loops, the primary cause of your error.

Comment: I would argue this is NOT a duplicate because the linked question does not deal with the question of how to bulkify a "LIKE" query. Which, granted, is not an easy proposition.

Comment: @CharlesT agree with you because i am able to resolve above one with check with map like contains sic.But i am losing my expected results.

Comment: What's confusing about your code though is, in the loop, you keep reassigning the value of the controller instance variable `listopp`. That means all results except the last iteration of the loop are discarded. Why are you querying only to immediately discard the results?

Comment: Yeah i too find out in final.I change my code as per criteria.Now,i stuck in case sensitive results because compare with map i'm unable to compare case sensitive.Any fix for this or i need to create separate for all lists.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most important best practices in Apex programing, and in most languages, is to never include DB acceses within loops. Specifically in Salesforce, there are Governor Limits that reign the platform. The reason for this is so an specific org doesn't consume too many resources, since the servers are shared. See [this post](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Multi_Tenant_Architecture) for more information the Multi Tenant Architecture they use.

Now, coming back to your issue, you are breaking with this practice exactly here:

```
        for(Opportunity opp: newopplist)
        {          
            if(!Siccodes.isEmpty())
            {
                Set<String> codes = new Set<String>();
                for(String code:Siccodes.keySet())
                {
                    codes.add(code + '%');
                }
                listopp=[Select Id,Name,StageName,Account.name,Number_of_Units__c,account.SIC_Code__c,Type,
                         Billing_City__c,Billing_State_Province__c,account.SIC_Industry_Name__c,
                         account.No_of_active_units__c from Opportunity where account.SIC_Code__c 
                         LIKE :codes and StageName='Closed Won' ORDER BY account.No_of_active_units__c Desc Limit 10];                    

            }
   }
```

The best way to handle this proble is to isolate DB acceses. I would recomend you to bring all the records you need in a single query and then distribute them in different structures like *Sets* or *Maps*, so you can later easily access them. For example, in an scenario where you need to edit certain opportunities related to the incoming accounts of a trigger, you would query for all the opportunities of all the accounts at the start of your code, and then loop over that list to sort them for each account.

I can't give you a more specific answer since we don't know your requirement, but that's the gist of the idea.

Comment: My requirement is i need to display related opportunities in lead page with  field called sic code in lead page.For example called sic=123 in lead page.so,now i need to display opportunities with sic code like 123,1234